# FFprobe to recursively search files to output to csv

Tags: bash, csv, directory, mp4, ffprobe

I am trying to run a bash script but am encountering some errors.

I want to recursively make the command search through the folder and look for all mp4 files. Then i want it to run the ffprobe command and output it to a csv file in a different location with the filename of the mp4 it ran with .csv

So far i have this

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in /this/is/directory1/*.mp4; do
    ffprobe -show_packets -of csv=print_section=0 $file >> /this/is/directory2/${file}.csv

done
```

Comment: What *errors* exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```sh
find . -type f -name "*.mp4" | xargs -I{} bash -c "ffprobe -show_packets -of csv=print_section=0 {} > /tmp/\$(basename {} | cut -d. -f1).csv"
```

OR without using `xargs`

```sh
find . -type f -name "*.mp4" -exec bash -c "ffprobe -show_packets -of csv=print_section=0 {} > /tmp/\$(basename {} | cut -d. -f1).csv" ';'
```

Change the path of directory output file in the command above.

Comment: Is there a way to make a new directory in the tmp automatically for the csv. For example, this/is/directory1/.mp4 then to create in the tmp folder /tmp/directory1/.csv

Comment: Damn it's a big command. `find . -type f -name "*.txt" | xargs -I{} bash -c "ffprobe -show_packets -of csv=print_section=0 {}  | mkdir -p /tmp/\$(basename \$(dirname {})) && tee /tmp/\$(basename \$(dirname {}))/\$(basename {} | cut -d. -f1).csv"`
 Not sure if it'll work

Comment: Ill try it. Is it possible also to add the filename to the .csv at the beginning maybe using a pipe or something "*.mp4" at the beginning of the csv file.

Comment: It should be, but it's very difficult to cram everything into a one liner script. The initial requirement you had was small enough. If you need more and more complexity to this, you should create a bash script that you were initially trying to do. That way you can keep the code readable and maintainable.